# How to programmatically invoke zoom event in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, callback

I am using "plot_google_map.m" that uses the Google Maps API to plot a map in the background of the current figure. A figure generated with this auto-refreshes the map upon zooming event, and I added some codes to make it refresh data upon panning event, too.

Now I would like to programmatically change the range of axes without using zoom or pan buttons, but the problem is map is not refreshed automatically. So, I am thinking of generating zooming or panning event programatically, but I haven't found a way to do that.
Any idea on this?

Let me elaborate my question.
In the 'plot_google_map.m', there is subfunction which is a callback of zooming event.

```
function plot_google_map  
% Listen to Zoom events    
h  = figure(1); plot(1:10);
hz = zoom(h);
set(hz,'ActionPostCallback',@mypostcallback);

function mypostcallback(obj,evd)
disp('Refreshes map data');
```

What I want to do is, to call this subfunction outside the 'plot_google_map'.
Any idea is welcomed, and thank you for your answers in advance!

Comment: Does `help axis` contain the information you need for zooming?

Answer (score 3):

You heard about the `zoom` command?

```
>> help zoom
 zoom   Zoom in and out on a 2-D plot.
```

Actually it seems that's how the program recognizes you zooming.

Comment: Thank you bdecaf, but I haven't found a way to solve this problem yet. So I've added some example code to explain my problem. Please have a look at this too.

Comment: so if you get the original figure handle using `get(hz,'ActionPostCallback')` - shouldn't you be able to execute it?

Comment: Great! This was the exact solution what I was looking for. Now I know how to get the handle of the zoom callback, and to execute it using retrieved handle. Thank you bdecaf.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your axes handle is `hAxes`, then you can do the zooming by changing the `xLim` and `yLim` properties of your axes rather than a zooming ratio, like the following:

If your plot is using the x axis from 0-100 then you can zoom in on a particular sub range og 0-100 for example:

```
set(hAxes,'xLim',[20 40])
```

and also for y axis you can zoom on a specific y range:

```
set(hAxes,'xLim',[30 70])
```

and if you want to zoom on a specific area on the plot, for example x[20-50],y[10-50], you can do it by doing the two previous action like:

```
set(hAxes,'xLim',[20 50])
set(hAxes,'yLim',[10 50])
```

**So**, change the `xLim` and `yLim` values of the axe depending on the size of your plot or your image, and that's how actually zooming work with axes.

You can even try this demo script:

```
 clear;clc;
 figure;
 h = axes;
 y = sin( 0:2*pi / 100:pi );
 plot(y);
 %// =============================
 pause(1);
 set(h , 'xlim' , [20 80]);
 %// =============================
 pause(1);
 set(h , 'xlim' , [30 40]);
 %// =============================
 pause(1);
 set(h , 'xlim' , [10 100]);
 %// =============================
 pause(1);
 set(h , 'ylim' , [.1 .4]);
 %// =============================
 pause(1);
 set(h , 'ylim' , [.2 .7]);
 %// =============================
 pause(1);
 set(h , 'ylim' , [.3 .9]);
 %// =============================
 pause(1);
 set(h , 'ylim' , [.1 .2]);
 set(h , 'xlim' , [10 80]);
 %// =============================
 pause(1);
 set(h , 'ylim' , [.3 .7]);
 set(h , 'xlim' , [40 90]);
 %// =============================
```

Comment: Thank you Sameh. I have tried your suggestions but the setting the 'xTick' only changes the labeling of the axes.

Comment: @SeungwooNoh .. I am so sorry it's not `xTick` or `yTick` , it's `xLim` and `yLim` .

Comment: @SeungwooNoh , I've fixed the code and added a demo for zooming on axes.

Comment: Thank you again Sameh. Your comments and sample code has been very helpful to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply call plot_google_map again after every time you change the axes range?
This will cause the map to be updated with the new extent.